# Can the Spyder window be reduced (Linux)?

Tags: linux, spyder

I'm not asking about showing or hiding the task bar via the "fullscreen" option.  What I can't see is a way to shrink the main Spyder window to something less than the full desktop area as can be done with most app windows.
I have run `conda update anaconda` and similar commands to make sure everything is up to date.

EDIT: This is under Ubuntu 14.10 standard installation.  No alternative desktops or themes involved.  I just launch Spyder via a Terminal command.

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Are you running Ubuntu? I mean, what is your desktop environment specifically?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba See added info (Ubuntu 14.10) in edited question. Thanks.

Comment: That seems more like a problem with Ubuntu than with Spyder. I'd have to create a virtual machine to test it, but that could take me a couple of weeks. Could you open an issue in our issue tracker so I don't forget about it?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Neeever mind.  I'm embarrassed now:  I had to hover the mouse *above* Spyder's menubar, in the "Ubuntu menu" bar, for lack of a better term, where typically all one sees is "**Spyder(Python2.7)**" . Once hovering there, the 3-button close/minimize/resize array is available.  Sorry.

Comment: I was imaging that (hence me asking about Ubuntu). Don't worry about it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a PEBCAK issue.  I just never expected to see window-control buttons **above** the menubar, but that's what happens.

I'm embarrassed now:  I had to hover the mouse *above* Spyder's menubar, in the "Ubuntu menu" bar, for lack of a better term, where typically all one sees is "**Spyder(Python2.7)**" . Once hovering there, the 3-button close/minimize/resize array is available.  Sorry.

Comment: I think in 'View' menu, there is an option for shrinking and resizing spyder layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just press the <kbd>F11</kbd> key (for Linux also).